# Gift amount allowed for directors in a company in Canada

Tags: gift-tax, canada-revenue-agency

What is the maximum amount can a small business owner give a director in their corporation as a gift? We are in Canada.

Answer (score 3):

There is no special gift tax in Canada. Cash or near-cash gifts and awards are [fully taxable as employment income](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/businesses/topics/payroll/benefits-allowances/gifts-awards-social-events/gifts-awards-outside-policy.html). Presumably, the limit is the amount of cash you've got.